# Does the Event Espresso plugin support Facebook as well as Eventbrite?

Tags: wordpress, events, plugins

I heard that [Event Espresso](http://eventespresso.com/) can do anything that the [Eventbrite](http://www.eventbrite.com/l/wordpress) do.
But I am confused about the Facebook part. Does it just support the useless share button and not the event link on the Facebook? And according to the showcase on their website, there are nothing special for me to think it is better than the normal event management.

I'm new to this area. And I really want to know if this plugin is really powerful as stated. I can't find a good case for study, and their website seems not well support for the users to find the useful information.

Is there a link of a wonderful website with this plugin or another plugin that do most things that Eventbrite do? Or some good tutorial about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Eventbrite your event is at the mercy and rules and fees of a 3rd party service.  With Event Espresso it's your event, you make the rules and you control everything and are not limited to somebody else's TOS.  Plus you aren't forced to use Paypal to sell your tickets.

I have used Event Espresso and it can do just about anything you need it to do.  All the templates are customizable along with the sign up forms etc..  Documentation is good but not so sure about the support.

Comment: I wonder to know if the event espresso can do the Facebook part such as make it an event of the Facebook not just add the share button on the website.